# Custom login instead of wordpress login

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I want to remove the login functionality of wordpress and add a custom login function that would check the username and password from my own database and accordingly display the admin,editor etc page. Please guide me through this process.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Honest question: why? You can customize the WP login process quite a bit, and it handles much of the heavy lifting for you.

Here's a toolkit I built for custom login pages and more: http://cferdinandi.github.io/web-app-starter-kit/